# Does the mysql Client API Library version have to match the installed MySQL/Percona server version?

Tags: mysql, centos, library, percona

I'm running Scientific Linux 6.3 (binary compaible with Redhat/CentOS/etc..) as a LAMP stack.

I've installed Percona server and client v5.5 from the Percona yum repository. However when I run phpinfo() I notice that under the MySQL and mysqli sections, it lists the Client API Library version as 5.1.66, and not 5.5x.

I'm guessing these need to match, at least to major versions, and I have no idea what the possible consequences of such a mismatch could be.

Do I need to revert to Percona server and client v5.1?

This is for a production environment so it needs to be right. I'd appreciate any input or experience people could offer.

I'm running Scientific Linux 6.3 (binary compaible with Redhat/CentOS/etc..) as a LAMP stack.

I've installed Percona server and client v5.5 from the Percona yum repository.  However when I run phpinfo() I notice that under the MySQL and mysqli sections, it lists the Client API Library version as 5.1.66, and not 5.5x.

I'm guessing these need to match, at least to major versions, and I have no idea what the possible consequences of such a mismatch could be.

Do I need to revert to Percona server and client v5.1?

This is for a production environment so it needs to be right.  I'd appreciate any input or experience people could offer.

(Note I will also be cross posting this on the Percona forums)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a v5.x client is fine against a v5.x server. The version number don't have to be an exact match and in fact for most cases even a v4.x, and possibly even earlier, client will work just fine against a v5.x server.